# How to assign value to a variable in select query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

I am migrating from mssql to postgresql

I am trying to assign a value to a temporary variable in select query

Below is the query in mssql

```
select flag = 0
```

It gives 0 as output wit flag as column identifier in mssql

I tried the following in postgresql

```
select flag := 0
select flag [:=0]
```

It says syntax error at or near :=

Does anybody know where I am going wrong?

Comment: I hope this will help you https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-variables/

Comment: That's not a "variable" that's a column (expression)

Answer (score 2):

> It gives 0 as output wit flag as column identifier in mssql

Postgres honors the SQL standard and a column alias is defined with the AS keyword there.

So to get a column named `flag` with the value zero use the following:

```
select 0 as flag
```

---

`flag = 0` in standard SQL (and Postgres) is a boolean expression that compares the the column `flag` with the value zero and returns either true, false or null depending on the column's value.